# How to run output from the batch file in c#.net

Tags: c#-4.0

I am trying to install a Windows Installer File i.e. BAT file which consist of DOS command.I want to run BAT file and extract DOS command from BAT file and re-run the DOS command, in order, to install proper driver. I did search a lot but I couldn't able to get solution for that. I am able to run .exe file.

here is my code -

```
ProcessStartInfo aProcessInfo;
Process aProcess = new Process();

aProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(command);
aProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = false;             
aProcessInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
aProcessInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
aProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

aProcess = Process.Start(aProcessInfo);
aProcess.WaitForExit();
```

My BAT file is install.bat; which when I click on edit open DOS command like

cls

msiexec /quiet /passive /i lcild_v207230.msi

in notepad.

Can anyone explain me how to extract and install driver from BAT file.

Thanks.

Comment: you mean you want to read the contents i.e. commands from the BAT file and run those commands from within your C# program. Is that right?

Comment: @Amn - Yes. I am trying to run those command from C# program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok then, this one just pops-up in my head. You can read the BAT file as a text file using File.Read or StreamReader class and then read the line that has the actual installation command i.e. the line with msiexec and then use your ProcessStartInfo class to start "msiexec". Make sure to pass whatever parameters that command needs, obviously a file name. See if that works.

Comment: BAT file is install.bat; when I right click on that file and edit it in notepad I can see the code. So what you're saying is read BAT file in notepad and then run the command. I am confused can you be little more elaborate.

Comment: Infact, you can run your BAT file from within your C# code, like so:

ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(<your batch file path>);
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo = psi;
            proc.Start();

why don't u try this direct approach, if all you want to do is run the BAT file from C# code.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368542%28v=vs.85%29.aspx this website describes this error code as : "This installation package could not be opened. Verify that the package exists and is accessible, or contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package." So make sure that the installation package is a valid one.

Comment: One last thing I want to ask you; when I do Run as Administrator for Batch file it did work and install the driver. Is it something different scenario to call from C# program?

Comment: if u run your Visual Studio as Administrator as well or even your C# program's exe, it should work in the same way as doing a "Run as Administrator" directly on the BAT file. Hope this helps.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15589/discussion-between-rushabh-shah-and-amn)